# Cognos Report Studio: Cascading Prompts populating really slow

Tags: query-optimization, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I've a Cognos report in which I've cascading prompts. The Hierarchy is defined in the image attached.

The First Parent (Division) fills the two cascading child in 3-5 seconds.
But when I select any Policy, (that will populate the two child beneath) it took around 2 minutes.

Facts:

- The result set after two minutes is normal (~20 rows)
- The Queries behind all the prompts are simple *Select DISTINCT Col_Name*
- Ive created indexes on all the prompt columns.
- Tried turning on the local cache and Execution Method to concurrent.
- I'm on Cognos Report Studio 10.1

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Nuh

[image]

Comment: First, try to cascade it only one of them and understand if the problem is in the AL-No or in the Claim No.
Index should be created on the where column, not on the display column. Do you scan fact table for a distinct values? that's not a good practice.

Comment: Hi Ran, sorry I missed that one. The issue is with the Al-No, if I remove AL from cascade, everything went well. Claim No. under Policy-No is filtered fast. Even Distinct Al-No's are displayed in seconds. The issue is when we want to filter Al-No as per selected Policy-No. There are a lot of duplicate Al-No's. Total is 36652106 and distinct are 22478. And I'm fetching this from a Detail Table.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about one thing, what is the query logic behind cascading? What actually happens at the query end when we are doing selections from cascading prompts? Any Idea where to dig?
Thanks.

Comment: What type of database are you querying from?

Comment: DW Content is stored in DB2

Comment: Prompts can be set to prepopulate with data.  Cascading prompts are seperate prompts, potentially with seperate queries, but which filter their prepopulation based on the prompts selected before them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative to a one-off dimension table.  Create a Query Subject in Framework for your AL-No prompt.  In the query itself, build a query that gets distinct AL-No (you said that is fast, probably because there is an index on AL-No).  Wrap that in a select that does a filter on ' #prompt('pPolicy')#'  (assuming your Policy Prompt is keyed to ?pPolicy?)

This will force the Policy into the sql before it is sent to the database, but wrapping on the distinct AL-No will allow you to use the AL-No index.

```
select AL_NO from 
(
    select AL_NO, Policy_NO
    from CLAIMS
    group by AL_NO, Policy_NO
)
where Policy_NO = #prompt('pPolicyNo')#
```

Comment: Hi There, your logic is really good. But how can this be applied if I'm fetching all the three columns from different query subjects. (Policy_no, Emp_Al_No and Claim_no) All these three are being fetched from different tables. There is a join logic between them.
I Believe, I'm stuck because the designers of the framework have designed it in that way. :\

Comment: My solution requires a change in Framework.  If you dont have access to that, it is not applicable.  If you want to preserve their setup, but can add new Data Sources, try creating a new Namespace, and put your own custom QuerySubjects in there.  Point the querysubject at your database.  You can have a separate query subject for each prompt query if you need, you dont HAVE to use a single query subject for mutliple different prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is just too much table scanning. Typically, one would build a prompt page from dimension-based tables, not the fact table, though I admit that is not always possible with cascading prompts. The ideal solution is to create a one-off dimension table with these distinct values, then model that strictly for the prompts.

Watch out for indexing each field, as the indexes will not be used due to the selectivity of the values. A compound index of the fields may work instead. As with any time you are making changes to the DDL - open SQL profiler and see what SQL Cognos is generating, then run an explain plan before/after the changes.

Comment: Hey Todd, yeah I was thinking on the same lines. There isn't any other option left. I cross checked the data fetching paradigm at framework and there the joining pattern is taking a lot of time. The Pattern has to be that way in order to fetch meaningful data.
Thanks for the insight man.